# CSS useless vendor prefixes

Tags: css, flexbox, vendor-prefix

I have a stylesheet that I made 2 or 3 years ago, when CSS was full of these horrible vendor prefixes for `flexbox`. I used flexboxes as needed, with the -webkit- prefix for Chrome & Safari.

I just saw on [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) that flexboxes are now working without prefix on every browsers. Do you know an up-to-date list of **CSS properties** that still need prefixes?

At that time, vendor prefixes were needed for things like gradients or animations. I wonder if I can remove everything safely, or if some of them are still used.

Comment: @dingo_d Not really, I don't want a list of prefixes, but a list of CSS properties for which prefixes are still needed

Comment: you may remove them to keep a clean and easy to maintain style sheet and add a javascript like autoprefixer or else that will generate the prefix  where and when needed only

Comment: How about [shouldiprefix.com](http://shouldiprefix.com)?

Comment: You can always just test your css in various browsers without using the annoying vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was looking for the same a while ago, and ran into [this useful website: Should I prefix?](http://shouldiprefix.com/). It lists the CSS properties and whether a prefix is still necessary or not.

Next to that, you can always check [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com) for more info and detail.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what was looking for : A quick overview

Comment: It is an overview, but it's not really updated. Check out the flexbox section. And then it just provides a link to caniuse.com.

Comment: I gets updated every now and then, see the Github commit log. E.g. [the flexbox property was updated last January](https://github.com/davidhund/shouldiprefix/commit/0a2ceda6f6cc28fd7f8ee22c1cc1bffd867660bb).

Answer (score 1):

+1 to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) as the best place to see browser prefix info. But your flexbox use case is unique.

Flexbox's implementation has changed a lot of the years, far more than almost any other CSS standard I am aware of. The best way to check which version you are using is to check the `display` value in your stylesheet.

- `display: box` is the oldest implementation, you probably didn't use this one.
- `display: flexbox` was the transitional state between the old and new flexbox standard. If you are 2-3 years out, you might have used this and will have to change your code to match the new implementation.
- `display: flex` is the modern implementation that has good cross browser support. If you used the prefix version of this, you should be able to safely drop prefixes and get the same results.

CSS Tricks has one of the best shorthands for the modern approach to flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/